Using other pallets in benchmarking
Im in pallet x - and in one of the benchmarking functions, i need to access a storage map from a pallet y. Hence what my approach was - add the pallet y in the cargo.toml dev dependencies of pallet x, and just import the storage map in my benchmark code like the below
use pallet_y::StorageMapExample;
and then access this in my benchmarking functions
I have added the pallet y in dev dependency - am i missing something else because my pallet y is not being recognised

dev-dependencies is a built-in field in Cargo, indicating that it is used for cargo test (development profile).
However, runtime-benchmarks is a customized feature flag specific to the polkadot-sdk. It is typically used with the command cargo build --features runtime-benchmarks ...
In your case, you should write something like:
[dependencies]
pallet-y = { optional = true, default-features = false, .. }

[features]
std = [
  "pallet-y?/std",
  ..
]

runtime-benchmarks = [
  "pallet-y",
  ..
]

